# Incrementar de cada 100 registros un nuevo valor de una consulta en php y sql

Tags: php, sql

Hola espero que  alguien  me  pueda  ayudar  soy  nuevo en  php y  tengo la  siguiente  pregunta  estoy  haciendo  un folio  que  se  genera de  una  base de  Datos esta  base  cuenta  con 3 campos: 
1.-id_folio 
2.-libro 
3.-folio

y  mi problema es el siguiente....
cada que  llegue  el  folio a 100 tendría  que  cambiar  el libro ejemplo:

```
 *Libro |   Folio
   0001 |   del folio 001 al folio 100.
   0002 |   del folio 101 al folio 200.
   0003 |   del folio 201 al folio 300.
   0004 |   del folio 301 al folio 400.
```

Este es mi código para generar el folio..

```
include('../../int/cone.php');

$sql2= mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM prueba ORDER BY id_folio DESC");
$sql2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2);    
$foliop=$sql2['id_folio']+1;
$libro = 1;

if ($foliop <'10'){$foliop = "00$foliop";}
elseif ($foliop <'100'){$foliop = "0$foliop";}

$folio=$foliop;

$sql = "INSERT INTO prueba (libro,folio)
VALUES ('$libro','$folio')";
if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    echo "Se Inserto Correctamente el Libro:&nbsp;$libro &nbsp;folio con el número :$folio";
}
```

El folio  se inserta correctamente , pero  no sé  como hacer  para  que  incremente  el libro cada  100 registros. de antemano  muchas gracias  por  leer mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

Algún algoritmo serviría, pero tendiras que evaluar como lo haras cuando 
el codigo llegué a al 10 luego al 100 ,podrias enredarte tratando de hayar
el algoritmo correcto, pero en la practica hay algo mas efectivo, como ya 
sabes que los folios iran de 100 en 100 lo mas sencillo seria trabajar con 
una consulta antes de hacer el insert.

para obtener el siguiente valor de la secuencia debes hacer un

```
SELECT MAX(Libro) AS indice From TABLA
```

Luego el nuevo valor seria

```
Libro       |   Folio

(indice)    |   del folio ((indice*100)-99) al folio (indice*100)
```

El único ajuste sería insertar el primer valor para poder hacer la consulta
o en su defecto si la consulta = NULL entonces sabes que es el primer registro
y por lo tanto insertas el primer valor, de lo contrario continuas con la inserción, ahora seria solo ver hasta cuantos registros deseas insertar en la tabla, eso lo debes definir en un bucle, pero no creo que tengas problemas con eso.

saludos.

[image: imagen de ejemplo]

Comment: hola  ken  muchas gracias  por  responder  pues  intente  como  tu  dices  con select  max  y nada entonces lo hice de  otra  forma  no es  muy  limpio  pero  funciona muy  bien 
abajo del folio puse lo siguiente  y funciono
$libro=""; 
if($id_foliop >= 0 ){
$libro="0";
if($id_foliop >= 10){
$libro="1";
}}  
if($id_folio >= 11 ){
$libro="1";
if($id_folio >= 20){
$libro="2";
}} 

y asi sucesivamente , pero tienes que darle a fuerza el valor hasta el numero que  quieres llegar al folio y libro